# How to add interstitial AdMob in iOS project with SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to implement interstitial AdMob to my game app. But I have not had much luck so far. The code doesn't seem to have a bug but however it does not display the app. Any help would be much appreciate it. Thank you!
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.



            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            skView.presentScene(scene)


        }


        interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5713504307801022/7610056592")


        let request = GADRequest()
        interstitial.loadRequest(request)

        func CreateAD() -> GADInterstitial {

            let interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-5713504307801022/7610056592")
            interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
            return interstital

        }


        if gameOver == true {


            if (interstitial.isReady){
                interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
                interstitial = CreateAD()

            }

        }

    }
```